# Why it uses 'nearest' here?

Tags: word-usage

In the Cambridge Dictionary online(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kerb), the explanation of the word 'kerb' goes as 'the edge of a raised path nearest the road'.

I checked the usage of 'nearest' and found out that it can only be used as an adverb or an adjective. However, judging from its position in the explanation (that is, between two nouns), it seems to serve as a preposition.

Is it wrong here? Should we replace 'nearest the road' by 'nearest to the road' or 'near the road'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/near?q=nearest), **near** is both an adverb and a preposition. Nearest is the superlative form of near, so nearest can definitely be an adverb (adverbs can form superlatives) and probably be a preposition.

The dictionary quotes this example: note that the **to** is optional.

> Which bus stop is nearest (to) your house?

For my part, I would usually include the **to** in writing, but might omit it in spoken English.

Comment: Wow, I thought a preposition has no superlatives.